# getElementById onchange results in object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to trigger a function when value of input_1 textbox changes.

i.e. getElementById('input_1').onchange results in object is not a function.

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" id="game_form"></form>
<table border="1" style="background-color:#FFFFCC;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #FFCC00;color:#000000;width:100" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_1"><input type="text" id="input_1" form="game_form" value="x"></td>
    <td id="cell_2"><input type="text" id="input_2" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_3"><input type="text" id="input_3" form="game_form"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_4"><input type="text" id="input_4" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_5"><input type="text" id="input_5" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_6"><input type="text" id="input_6" form="game_form"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_7"><input type="text" id="input_7" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_8"><input type="text" id="input_8" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_9"><input type="text" id="input_9" form="game_form"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(
    function checkInput() {
//        alert("I am an alert box!1");
        var cell = document.getElementById('input_1');
        alert(cell.value);
        **document.getElementById('input_1').onchange**(
            doSomething()
        );
    }
);


function doSomething(){
    alert("I am an alert box!2");

}
```

Comment: Why not `<input type="text" id="input_1" form="game_form" value="x" onchange="doSomething(this)">` where `this` will be the target input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. You want [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
var el = document.getElementById("input_1");
el.addEventListener("change", doSomething, false);
```

Or with jQuery:

```
var $el = $('#input_1');
$el.on('change', doSomething);
```

Comment: The OP has jQuery - more likely he wants `.on('change', ...)`

Comment: _You want_ always sounds like something between order(command) and hypnosis, doesn't it? :)

Comment: hi, ok now I have hit another issue.  I want to pass the jquery variable to another function and in that function, it will display a msg popup displaying the variable value
    

    $(window).load(
        function checkInput() {
            var $el = $('#input_1');
            $el.on('change', $el, doSomething);
    
        }
    );
    
    function doSomething($el){
        alert($el.text());
    }

Comment: @Damien Best to ask a new question I think.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.onchange` is property, not function.

You can, by the way, use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this:

```
$('#input_1').on("change", function()
{
    doSomething();
});
```

Or [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) shortcut for `.on("change", ...`:

```
$('#input_1').change(function()
{
    doSomething();
});
```

If you somewhy want to use `onclick` instead of `.change()` and `.addEventListener()`, you can use it this way:

```
document.getElementById('input_1').onchange = doSomething;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv65ccjw/).

Comment: Coding suggestion - _always_ use `.on('change', ...)` instead of `.change` so that it's obvious whether the call is a _registration_ or a _trigger_ (and always use `.trigger` for the latter, too!)

Comment: @Alnitak well, I suppose you understand that it is obvious enough for those who know what difference is, and others most probably don't know about difference's existance.

Comment: @Regent personally I wish the jQuery devs would deprecate the shortcut versions.

Comment: @Alnitak well, I use `.on()` in my projects, but I'm not sure whether different behaviour of `.change()` based on arguments is good idea or not. Adding handler to event and triggering this event  are not very different (not connected with each other) functions. But, on the other hand, if I use different set of arguments in same-name-method declarations in Java or C#, they all do the same, just some arguments have default values or are converted to required types.

Comment: The other rationale is that it's far easier to search for `.on` to find all event registrations in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Onchange is not a function, is a property.
You must set onchange equal to the function you want.

```
document.getElementById('input_1').onchange = function(){
//Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery selector to bind onchange or use javascript event binding method to achieve this.

So this would be `$('#input_1').change(function() { });`

OR

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('input_1');

myEl.addEventListener('change', function() {
   // do something
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#input_1').change(function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

This will work!

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with jquery, you can use the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // when all DOM is loaded
    $('#input_1').on('change',function(){ // # is id based selector
        // you event handler logic
    });
});
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ // When DOM is ready...
 $('input').on('change',function(){ // Every Input field would get into this Event... to change only for id=input_1 -> '#input_1'
  //Alternative to 'change' would be 'keyup', because change is only called when the input field losts his focus...
  alert(this.id);
  switch(this.id)
        {
            case 'input_1': alert('input 1!');
              break;
            case 'input_2': alert('input 2!');
              break;
            //....
        }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="background-color:#FFFFCC;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #FFCC00;color:#000000;width:100" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_1"><input type="text" id="input_1" form="game_form" value="x"></td>
    <td id="cell_2"><input type="text" id="input_2" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_3"><input type="text" id="input_3" form="game_form"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_4"><input type="text" id="input_4" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_5"><input type="text" id="input_5" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_6"><input type="text" id="input_6" form="game_form"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_7"><input type="text" id="input_7" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_8"><input type="text" id="input_8" form="game_form"></td>
    <td id="cell_9"><input type="text" id="input_9" form="game_form"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Greetings